# React Native Router flux action.key() doesn't work

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I am building a project on React Native, I am new to React Native. But unfortunately the Actions.key() not working. Here is my code details

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import Spinner from './components/common/Spinner'; 
import reducers from './reducers';
import Router from './Router';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    renderLoading = () =>
{
 <Spinner size="large" />;  
}
    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root2',
      storage: AsyncStorage  
    }
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers) 
    const store = createStore(persistedReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    const persistor = persistStore(store);
    return (

      <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Router />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;


LoginForm.js



import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser, loginUserSuccess1 } from '../actions';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button, Spinner } from './common';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import NameEnter from './NameEnter';
import Router from '../Router';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  componentDidMount()
  {

    console.log (this.props.userDetails); 
    if(this.props.userDetails != null) 
    {
    if (this.props.userDetails.success !== false) {
      console.log (this.props.userDetails.success);
      this.props.loginUserSuccess1(this.props.userDetails);    

    }   
  }     
    //Actions.screen1();   

  }
  onEmailChange(text) {

    this.props.emailChanged(text);
  }

  onPasswordChange(text) {
    this.props.passwordChanged(text);
  }

  onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.props;

    this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
  }

  renderButton() {
    // if (this.props.loading) {
    //   return <Spinner size="large" />;
    // }

    return (
      <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
        Login
      </Button>
    );
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <Card>

        <CardSection>
          <Input
            label="Email"
            placeholder="email@gmail.com"
            onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.props.email}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Input
            secureTextEntry
            label="Password"
            placeholder="password"
            onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.props.password}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>
          {this.props.error}
        </Text>

        <CardSection>
          {this.renderButton()}
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  errorTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red'
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
  const { email, password, error, loading , userDetails } = auth;

  return { email, password, error, loading , userDetails };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser, loginUserSuccess1
})(LoginForm);
```

AuthActions.js

```
 import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
    import axios from 'react-native-axios';


    import {
      EMAIL_CHANGED,
      PASSWORD_CHANGED,
      LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
      LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
      LOGIN_USER,
      URL
    } from './types';

    export const emailChanged = (text) => {

      return {
        type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
        payload: text
      };

    };

    export const passwordChanged = (text) => {
      return {
        type: PASSWORD_CHANGED,
        payload: text
      };
    };

    export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
      return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

      axios.post(URL + '/hostLogin', {
          email: email,
          password: password
        })
        .then((user) => {
          console.log(user.data);
          loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          loginUserFail(dispatch);
        });
        // firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        //   .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
        //   .catch((error) => {
        //     console.log(error);

        //     firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        //       .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
        //       .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
        //   });
      };
    };

    const loginUserFail = (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL });
    };

    const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {

      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user.data
      });

      Actions.main();
    };
    export const loginUserSuccess1 = (user) => {
      console.log(1);
      return {
        type: 'Navigate',
        payload: 'Success'
      };


    };
```

AuthReducer.js

```
import {
  EMAIL_CHANGED,
  PASSWORD_CHANGED,
  LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
  LOGIN_USER
} from '../actions/types';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
   userDetails: null,
  error: '',
  loading: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, email: action.payload };
    case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, password: action.payload };
    case LOGIN_USER:
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
    console.log(action.payload );
      return { ...state, userDetails: action.payload }; 
    case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
      return { ...state, error: 'Authentication Failed.', password: '', loading: false };
      case 'Navigate':
      console.log(2);
      Actions.main();  
       default: 
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is Router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import NameEnter from './components/NameEnter';


const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
    <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
      <Scene key="auth" >
        <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
      </Scene>
      <Scene key="main">
        <Scene key="screen1" component={NameEnter} title="Please Enter Your Name " />
      </Scene>
      </Scene>
    </Router> 
  );
};

export default RouterComponent;
```

Now in Authreducer.js i am using Actions.main() to navigate to main . But that is not working . Is something wrong with the settings of router . Please help

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you have mixed react native commands with redux. What i have noted is that redux always loads first before react native libraries etc loads so it will not work, you have to separate them to make them work.

You can separate them by returning true (also remove Actions.main() from redux file switch statements) and you will read this response from another file(this file will be react native component) where you can use Actions.main() and then it will work.

Comment: Actually its not working from any react Native component also

Comment: Are you getting 2 in console.log, other Actions.something() are working ? try to change like this syntax in router : `<Router>
    <Stack key="root">
      <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login"/>
      <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register"/>
      <Scene key="home" component={Home}/>
    </Stack>
  </Router>` i can understand it better if you create a github repo of this example

Comment: Yes i am getting 2 in console log

Comment: Actions.something() should definitely work on components, you are making some mistake i can't figure that out unless i know your whole code where you have used Actions.main() in a component

Answer (score 0):

From the [redux documentations](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers):

> "Given the same arguments, it [*reducers*] should calculate the next state and return it. No surprises. No side effects. No API calls. No mutations. Just a calculation."

Reducers should always stay pure. It's an **antipattern to perform routing** transitions inside a reducer.

**Beside this:** I had the same issue with *react native 0.57.0* and *react-native-router-flux v4*, which is based on React Navigation v2.x. Every method except .key() was working, so I had to downgrade back to *rnrf 4.0.0-beta.32*. It doesn't seem to be a bug and is more likely caused by a dependency version mismatch (e.g. react & react-native). I will dig deeper into this issue and hopefully find a way to use the newer versions.

Comment: So what will be the npm command to downgrade that i am new to npm

Comment: npm install react-native-router-flux@4.0.0-beta.32 --save

Comment: Yes i did that still not working i am switching to react native navigation